# Create method similar to the .css() function of JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, function, methods

It is possible to create a method that is similar with the `.css()` function from jQuery?

Example in jQuery:

```
$("#elemid").css("position","absolute");
$("#elemid").css({position:"absolute",left:45});
```

And I want this to look almost the same in JAVA

Example in JAVA

```
Rectangle rect=new Rectangle();
rect.style("position","absolute");
rect.style({position:"absolute",left:45});
```

Comment: Nothing so far ,but I think this is possible with an enum

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similiar creating a DSL on your own. An example of DSL library is [JooQ](http://www.jooq.org/manual/DSL/), a java DSL for SQL.

It will require some work, though :P

Comment: Creating a DSL in Java for something like wouldn't really be worth the effort. Ruby on the other hand...

Comment: True, but unfortunately he wants to do it in Java :/

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of the JQuery functions is that they return a new (or the same) object for you to potentially call another method on. A similar approach it implemented in the .NET Framework's `System.Linq` namespace. Although that one makes use of extension methods, those are just a way to define additional methods for existing classes. An example:

```
foreach (var i in list.Skip(4).TakeWhile(x => x > 0).Select(x => x*x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

This skips the first four elements of the list, then iterates over the remaining elements until it either reaches the end of the list or an element that's not greater than zero. Each of the elements iterated over is squared and then returned by the iterator to be written to the console.

So, if you create your own classes in Java, simply let the methods return an object to call additional methods on. The `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` classes already do that with their `Append` methods by simply returning `this`.

Comment: and how can I use this in java.Hoe can I call the method?